# RouteReuseStrategy slow down Angular 4 application

Tags: angular, routes

I'm facing an issue when using RouteReuseStrategy on my Angular 4 application. In fact, the application is slowing down when I'm navigating : the more I change route the more it slows down.

Here's the code I'm using for my CustomReuseStrategy :

```
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouteReuseStrategy, DetachedRouteHandle } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthComponent } from '../auth/auth.component';

export class CustomReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {

  handlers: { [key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle } = {};

  /**
   * Determines if this route (and its subtree) should be detached to be reused later.
   * Fired when shouldReuseRoute returns false
   * If it returns true, the method store will be fired.
   * @param route current route
   */
  shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * Determines the action we want to do when storing a route.
   * Fired when shouldDeatch returns true.
   * @param route : current route
   * @param handle : identifies the stored component
   */
  store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
    let url: string = this.getRouteIdentifier(route);
    if (route.data['shouldReuseRoute']) {
      this.handlers[url] = handle;
    } else {
      delete (this.handlers[url]);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Determines if the current route should be reused from the stored components or not.
   * Fired when shouldReuseRoute returns false
   * @param route current route
   */
  shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    let url: string = this.getRouteIdentifier(route);
    // Reset all the stored routes if we're on the AuthComponent
    if (route.component === AuthComponent) {
      this.handlers = {};
      return false;
    }
    return !!route.routeConfig && !!this.handlers[url];
  }

  /**
   * Determines which route we want to retrieve if shouldAttach returns true.
   * Fired when shouldAttache returns true
   * @param route current route
   */
  retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
    let url: string = this.getRouteIdentifier(route);
    if (!route.routeConfig) {
      return null;
    }
    return this.handlers[url];
  }

  shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    let currentUrl: string = this.getRouteIdentifier(curr);
    let futureUrl: string = this.getRouteIdentifier(future);
    return currentUrl === futureUrl;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the unique identifier for each route
   * @param route: route to identify
   */
  getRouteIdentifier(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): string {
    return route.url.join('/');
  }

}
```

I have some really particular cases where I need to reuse routes, so in average, I have maximum 2 routes stored.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Share your route config details. Can you confirm only two 2 are stored? Check the size of store and no of snapshot in DetachedRouteHandle . You could try clearing old snap shot from DetachedRouteHandle before you store and just keep only one snapshot. I haven't tried this.

Comment: I confirm that I have only 2 routes stored, because I added console.log(this.handlers) in all the functions. So, that doesn't seem to be the problem. I've tried to implement my class differently, and it seems like my performance problems are solved, I don't really know how...

Comment: Although you might only store 2 routes, you still return true for shouldReuseRoute/shouldDetach, this will cause `ngOnDestroy` NOT to be called, thus leaking any subscriptions and external resources you might have going on in the components.